# test for empty cell and then convert number text

Tags: text, excel-formula, phone-number

I  have always had a problem importing phone numbers from CSV files into Outlook. Now I am working with Excel to clean up the telephone fields which should be in +1 545 254-2351 format.

I need to first test to see if the cell is empty containing the telephone number and if false to convert the contents of the cell to TEXT. I have written the following formula to no avail.

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(A5),"",ISTEXT(A5),A5,TEXT(A5,0))
```

In theory if A5 is blank it will return a blank cell. If it is not blank then if A5 is TEXT the result will be just A5. If it is not text i.e. a number, then it converts a5 to text.

This does not work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that **A5** can contain either:

1. Text like: *+1 545 254-2351*
2. blank
3. Number like:  *15452542351*

Then in **B5** enter:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A5),"",IF(ISTEXT(A5),A5,("+" & LEFT(TEXT(A5,"@"),1) & " ") & MID(TEXT(A5,"@"),2,3) & " " & MID(TEXT(A5,"@"),5,3) & "-" & RIGHT(TEXT(A5,"@"),4)))
```

[image]